# Datepicker returning only date

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datepicker

Im using the Datepicker control to get a date and display it in a Textblock in WP7. I want it to only show the date and not the time. The Datepicker only shows the date, but when I want to show it in the TextBlock it shows both date and time. I use databinding to set the date in the Datepicker:

```
public class Task
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Task()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Date}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
<TextBlock x:Name="TxbTaskDate" Text="{Binding Date}" />
```

How do I get the TextBlock to only show the date and not time?

Comment: You may also need to think about localisation. Some of the answers do direct formatting with day/month/year parts but in some countries (such as the US) they do month/day/year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a StringFormat

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TxbTaskDate" 
           Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TxbTaskDate" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" />
```

Comment: I prefer this as it will pick up the users locale

Answer (score 1):

A .NET DateTime always includes the Time. Your issue is with formatting in the TextBlock

```
<!-- untested -->
<TextBlock x:Name="TxbTaskDate" Text="{Binding Date StringFormat={0:dd-MM-yyyy}}" />
```

Comment: If this does everything you need, it's a simpler solution than a `ValueConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` includes a time component, as it's name suggests. You can use a `ValueConverter` in your `TextBlock` binding to strip off the time and display only the date.

At a high level, the `ValueConverter` will take one type, like a `DateTime`, and allow you to do some conversions on it. I would probably have it return a formatted `string`:

```
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);
```

Here's a [good intro to `ValueConverter`](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx), if you haven't used one before.