# WPF TimePicker Control get only required fields

Tags: wpf, timepicker

i am using TimePicker control for the first time.
I want to get the selected time into my ViewModel as well as bind the sele.cted time into a textblock/textbox.
I am Able to bind the TextBox to selected to selected value But it displays Date As well with time.
I want to display only time meaning, get only time from TimePicker.

the textbox data looks like- 2/8/2015 10:18:35 PM
What want to display is - 10:18:35 PM

I dont understand why TimePicker should display date?? If so i could go for DateTimePicker control.
But now i need only time to be selected and displayed.
Here is my code trying to get it..
Please help me with this......!

Here is my code trying to get it..

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:Data></vm:Data>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TimePick:TimePicker Name="tp" Format="LongTime"  FormatString="hh:mm tt" Margin="10,52,174,244"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=tp}"  Margin="0,127,174,153"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're only using the `TimePicker` control? If so i guess it should only display the `time`. If you're using the `DateTimePicker` control then you have to split in order to display only the date or the time:

[Datepicker returning only date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762463/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739768/how-to-change-timepicker-format-using-properties)

Did you try out other `TimePicker` controls out there?

[What is currently the best, free time picker for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833357/)

Comment: Hello..! Yes I am Using TimePicker Control which is the extended wpf toolkit.

Comment: But when I bind its value to a textbox it displays  time but date also with it..! As I change the time through dropdown, its updating fine. But its having date also with it..! So please provide a suggestion/solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try adding the `Format String` within your `TextBox`:
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=tp, StringFormat='{}{hh:mm tt}'}"  Margin="0,127,174,153"></TextBox>

Comment: No..! It has No effects..!! with this string format, its Not even updating now.! Tried altering it too..!!